# Is it possible to control Packer from golang?

Tags: continuous-integration, infrastructure-as-code, go

We use Terraform quite a bit and it has some nice tooling like Terratest where you can essentially call Terraform from within Golang wrapped inside an API with proper error handling.

I wonder if something similar exist for Packer?

To clarify what I what to do with it:
This code will be part of a CI/CD workflow, and we would love to automatically build an AWS AMI. But there is some logic involved so ideally we'd love to be able to control packer from golang.

Comment: Not something that I have come across. Packer does have a good templating language so we've not really seen the need to wrap it. We just pass the parameters we need to the template to build our AWS AMIs

Comment: Packer is just another command you would run.  Is there anything special about that would cause Golang problems?